Nginx Proxy, Cloudflare Full SSL, and Load Balancer Redirection Loop?
I'm facing an issue with a redirection loop when using Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of my load balancer. My setup is as follows:
Domain: aarohisilks.com DNS: Cloudflare, A record pointing to my proxy server's IP, SSL mode set to "Full-strict" Proxy Server (Nginx): Terminates SSL, forwards traffic to the load balancer on port 80 Load Balancer (Nginx): Distributes traffic to backend servers
Proxy Configuration inside my proxy server
/etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy.conf
# Temporary configuration for ACME challenge
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^.*$;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/html;
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}

 #Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for all domains
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^.*$;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


# SSL configuration for proxy subdomain
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name gateway.enlivendesigners.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gateway.enlivendesigners.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gateway.enlivendesigners.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://load_backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
# SSL configuration for staging subdomains
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name staging.aarohisilks.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.aarohisilks.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.aarohisilks.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://staging_backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
# SSL configuration for production subdomains
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name aarohisilks.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/aarohisilks.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/aarohisilks.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://load_backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Proxy Upstream Configuration /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf
upstream load_backend {
    #server 194.163.168.18;  # Prod1 server
    server 148.135.73.76; #loadbalncer
}

upstream staging_backend {
    server 81.0.218.72;  # Staging server
}

Load Balancer Configuration (/etc/nginx/sites-available/load_balancer.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name aarohisilks.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://production_backend;
        # ... (proxy headers)
    }
}

Load Balancer Upstream Configuration (/etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf)
upstream production_backend {
    server 194.163.168.18; 
    server 194.163.166.206; 
}

When I try to access my website, I get the error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS." or it wont load entirely. I suspect this is due to a redirection loop caused by the following:

The proxy redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS. This causes a
continuous loop of redirects between Cloudflare and the proxy.

I've verified that the backend servers (194.163.168.18 and 194.163.166.206) are working correctly.
Also I have sent the request to only to the proxy without any load balancer I declare my server ip in upstream conf.
In my live server which is ip 194.163.168.18, 194.163.166.206 I have installed cyberpanel and using cyberpanel I am hosting wordpress websites. Without the load balancer site works well.
Are there any potential configuration changes I should make to either my proxy server, load balancer, or Cloudflare settings?
All the ports are opn 443,80,22

If you have CF terminating ssl, then you don't need to ssl and http-to-https redirects on your server.

You should check what are the HTTP response headers for the redirect. With those, you can deduce which component actually sends the redirect. Then you can investigate why that component sends the redirect. My educated guess: Some component is configured to be https only, and when requests come to that component via HTTP, it sends redirect to https.
